# How to call an inherited method from a Singleton?

Tags: c#, singleton

I'm dealing with an issue when trying to use the singleton pattern. It seems very simple but it taking me longer than usual.

**This is the scenario:**

In a first assembly we have:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public void Method()
}
```

In other assembly:

```
public sealed class DerivedClass: BaseClass
{
    private static DerivedClass _instance;

    public static DerivedClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new DerivedClass();
            }

            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private void TestMethod()
    {
        //here is working perfect!
        DerivedClass.Instance.Method();
    }    
}
```

However, when I trying to use it from outside the **DerivedClass** this way, also in another assembly:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    ...
    DerivedClass.Instance.Method() //do not compile! :s
    ...
}
```

its telling me that:

> does not contain a definition for 'Method()' and no extension method 'Method'

Its important to say that I CAN'T set the **BaseClass** as *static*. Also, I tried to set the definition of method as *protected virtual*, but it didn't work too.

What am I doing wrong? Sorry if the question seems too easy.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a singleton, since you have a public constructor. You need to make it private so the static Instance property is the way to gain access to the single instance. I have used this code, which compiles and works perfectly.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DerivedClass.Instance.Method());
        Console.WriteLine(DerivedClass.TestMethod());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public string Method()
    {
        return "yo";
    }
}

public sealed class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    private static DerivedClass _instance;

    private DerivedClass()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public static DerivedClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new DerivedClass();
            }

            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public static string TestMethod()
    {
        //here is working perfect!
        return DerivedClass.Instance.Method();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry james, that wasn't the problem because when I tried to simplify the question a remove all the return types an stuff like that and I forgot to do it in SomeMethod(). Thanks anyway... what you said was right!

Comment: Could you post a more complete set of code, I have edited my answer and it compiles and works just fine

Comment: I found the problem, now I will update the answer. I upvote you anyway!

Comment: Thanks! finally hit that 200 rep mark so I can actually do stuff on the programmers stack exchange :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had no referenced the assembly that contains **BaseClass** into the one which makes use of **DerivedClass**, in this case, the third one.

So, the project with *SomeMethod* has to reference both.